# Convert XPath into CssSelector for Jsoup

Tags: java, xpath, css-selectors, jsoup

I have this xpath: `//a[contains(text(), 'My Text')]` and I want to convert it to css.

I tried with `a:contains('My Text')` but not work.

Comment: What is the problem with XPath?

Comment: @AndiCover `Jsoup` don't support `XPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to quote the text. Just use `a:contains(My Text)`.
Example: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax